# Assigning array values to variable

Tags: shell-script

Can anybody please tell me how to assign array value to a variable?

```
Var1 =${myarray[0]}
echo "$Var1"
```

Why am I getting errors while trying the above scenario?

Answer (score 4):

You were very close.

There must not be any whitespace around `=` in variable declaration.

Do:

```
Var1=${myarray[0]}
```

Comment: bash arrays index starts at 1

Answer (score -2):

in bash you cannot operate on variables like you do in any other language. 
however this page may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691942/bash-print-array-elements-on-separate-lines

regards